# Multiline pdf text box

Tags: pdf, adobe, pdf-form

I am trying to create a multiline text field , however on doing this the text doesn't fit within the lines that are present in the form design.
[image: text overlaps line]

Now one solution is to increase the font size , I have tried that and it doesn't really solve it.

This is a government form that works fine when you download from their site and open in adobe reader. ( and they have even smaller font ). See image below.

[image: original form works fine]

I am using adobe acrobat pro dc , Build: 18.11.20055.290043 , and I don't see an option to control line height for a multiline field.

Interestingly enough , even the government form above that works fine upon downloading , has the same line overlapping problem if type text within chrome using the adobe reader plugin.

How can I adjust the line height ?? I read somewhere to set paragraph line spacing in text field properties , but I do not see this option anywhere.

[image]

Comment: You need to use Rich Text formatting in order to control the line height.

Comment: That doesn't work .. I have scoured the internet for everything and tried, before posting such a long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the field to Allow Rich Text Formatting then while in the field, show the properties bar.
[image]

From there click the "More" button to get the text field properties dialog, select Paragraph and then use the Line Spacing drop down.

[image]

You can also set these properties programmatically by creating a JSON representation of the rich content and then setting the field.richContent property.

Comment: Thanks. How do I open "Form field text properties" , hitting cmd + E on the rich text field shows "Text field properties" on my acrobat ( which is somewhat similar to your popup)  , and clicking more shows the same "text field properties" popup shown above , that originally allowed me to set "rich text".  Which version of acrobat are you using , I am using acrobat pro dc version 2018.011.20055.

Comment: You need to be in the field and have some text selected, then right-click on the main toolbar and select "Show Properties bar"