# How can I set the line height of a multi-line PDF form field, and save it so it doesn't get reset by filling it?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, pdf-form

I am having the exact same issue described in this question: [Multiline pdf text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049284/multiline-pdf-text-box)

I have a PDF that has some dotted lines that I want to convert into a fillable multi-line field. I tried the solution in the linked question, but my setting is **not staying** when I try to fill in the field outside of Acrobat.

When I am preparing the form inside Acrobat, I set the line height to 30 and it is lining up fine:
[image]

But when I save this PDF and then try to fill in the field outside of Acrobat, the line height setting does not stay. It gets reset every time:
[image]

It's super frustrating and I have scoured the internet looking for an answer but I have nothing yet. If someone knows what to do to get the line height looking like the first screenshot, please save my sanity.

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 2021.001.20135 on macOS 10.14.6.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Those settings don't "stick" when the field is cleared and there's no way to set them programmatically. It's best to simply remove the lines from the PDF.

Comment: Hmm… does your statement mean that Adobe messed up the richValue field property?

Comment: No. That setting, among others is a property of the richText, not a property of the field. If it were a property of the field, the PDF Spec would need to be updated to support it. Within the richText value, Adobe, or any other vendor, can support whatever they want.

Adobe had to operate within the PDF spec.

Comment: OK, so, we could do some trickery to make a richText field kind of reset-proof; a little bit messy, but should work. (I am just about to deal with such a document…)

Comment: @joelgeraci not that I’m doubting you in any way, but do you have any official source that says this? Such as a page by Adobe or similar? I’m making this doc for a client who will likely insist on the extra credibility behind this answer. I find it super weird that what I’d consider to be a basic requirement like this is so hard to do on a PDF...

Comment: @Sidewinder - Yes - The PDF Specification, Table 225 – CSS2 style attributes used in rich text strings. While there is a vertical-align property, it applies to super and sub scripts, not the vertical alignment of the content. Also, I was the product manager for forms for Acrobat 3.5, 4, 5, and 6 and I know that this aspect of the form features haven't changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

As @joelgeraci stated, the settings don't stick.

However, if the form has to be manually fillable, removing the writing lines may not be the best idea. In this situation, it would be better to change the field's background color. When the field has no content, its background color is transparent, otherwise white. And that will cover the writing lines.

Comment: That’s actually a pretty great solution - could you please guide me on how to do this?